# Spring @Profile works on class, but not on @Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm unable to get `@Profile` to work on a `@Bean`, but it works fine on the `@Configuration` class.  In my module tests I correctly get the `MyServiceStub` autowired in the first example, but not in the second.

Does anyone know why?

This works:

*MyConfig.java*

```
@Configuration
@Import({StubConfig.class, RealConfig.class}
public class MyConfig {}
```

*StubConfig.java*

```
@Profile({"featureTest", "moduleTest"})
@Configuration
public class StubConfig {

  @Bean
  public MyService myService() {
    return new MyServiceStub();
  }
}
```

*RealConfig.java*

```
@Profile({"!featureTest", "!moduleTest"})
@Configuration
public class RealConfig {

  @Bean
  public MyService myService() {
    return new MyService();
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work:

*MyConfig.java*

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

  @Bean
  @Profile({"featureTest", "moduleTest"})
  public MyService myServiceStub() {
    return new MyServiceStub();
  }

  @Bean
  @Profile({"!featureTest", "!moduleTest"})
  public MyService myService() {
    return new MyService();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an explicit profile called `"!moduleTest"`?

Comment: Has been working for me, but I haven't used the curly braces. Could you try removing the curly braces and see?

Comment: @Sanjay:  That's how an annotation with more than one value is declared.  The value for `@Profile` is a `String[]`, so the braces are implicit if there's one element in the array.

Comment: @Makato: Yeah. It has been working for me, so I asked just to confirm. (I have a quite similar example, including the !, which would mean not.)

Comment: @Makato No. "!moduleTest" means "NOT moduleTest".

Comment: Could you elaborate on what isn't working?

Comment: @M.Deinum Good point, I've edited the question:  With the working example, my module tests get get right autowired bean (MyServiceStub).  With the second example it doesn't.

Comment: @Sanjay: Good to know that it should work.  I'll have to dig a little more.

Comment: Please add your test case.

Comment: I have the same issue, it is supposed to work, it is not working

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using @Profile approach, you could try using the @Conditional to have [conditional](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-4-conditional-bean-configuration/) bean creation.

Or have an explicit `if-stmt` to check what is the [activeProfile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html#getActiveProfiles--). And you can create the Bean instance depending on the activeProfile. This approach I think would mirror what could be done in Spring XML using their expression language. But the @Conditional seems better fit for you.

Comment: Your answer starts with "I am not sure" but it's [easy to verify](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) that `@Profile` allows prefixing with ! for a "NOT", it can be also used on `@Bean`-annotated method. Looks like OP's question doesn't include enough infomation to diagnose the problem. Reimplemting the `@Profile` behaviour using `@Conditional` instead of getting to the bottom of the problem feels like a lazy workaround.